# printing from a list TKinter

Tags: python, list, tkinter, printing

Trying to print the months in the list in column 0 of the grid in tkinter. But the output is overlapped printing in a cell. Couldn't trace out the problem.

```
#!/bin/env /python
from Tkinter import *

akhilGui = Tk()
akhilGui.geometry('600x500')
month_list = ["April 2020","May 2020","June 2020", "july 2020","August 2020", "September 2020","October 2020","November2020", "December 2020", "January 2020","February 2020", "March 2020"] #initialise the variable row_value to be used in grid()
lab_list = []
def lab_print ():
        for i in month_list:                        #iterating through the list, creating label
        #iLabel          = str(i) + "Label"
        #iEntry          = str(i) + "Entry"
            row_value = 5
            row_value = row_value + 1
            iLabel          = Label(akhilGui, text= str(i),
                                fg="#113B53",font = "Helvetica  12 bold ", justify='right')
            lab_list.append(iLabel)
            iLabel.grid(row = row_value, column=0, pady=2, padx=15, sticky= W)

lab_print ()


akhilGui.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move the line `row_value = 5` before the for loop:

```
def lab_print ():
        row_value = 5
        for i in month_list:   #iterating through the list, creating label
            row_value = row_value + 1
            iLabel = Label(akhilGui, text= str(i),
                                fg="#113B53",font = "Helvetica  12 bold ", justify='right')
            lab_list.append(iLabel)
            iLabel.grid(row = row_value, column=0, pady=2, padx=15, sticky= W)
```

Comment: Thank you ! Your reply solved the problem!!